# Get notified when <video> time changes

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, youtube

I would like to display the current percentage of the video using a Firefox extension.

I know I can get the current time and the duration with the [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference):

```
player = document.getElementById('movie_player')
currentTime = player.getCurrentTime()
duration = player.getDuration()
```

And I can add a node to the DOM with `appendChild` or `insertBefore`.

But I don't understand how to update periodically the DOM as time goes by.

I tried to understand how the Youtube Player updates the time display using the inspector but it didn't help me:

[image: Time display]

[image: Inspector]

I guess I should use events somehow but I don't know what event could be triggered periodically without user intervention (click, hover, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for the [`timeupdate` Media Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events):

> The time indicated by the element's currentTime attribute has changed.

```js
const vid = document.querySelector('video')

vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', e => {
  console.log(vid.currentTime)
})
```

```html
<video autoplay width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```